# Descriptive term for oil in water or visa versa?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have seen a lot of questions come through for water in the oil (chocolate milk) or oil in the water ... What could we use as a term to throw into a tag for either one of these? I mean, I guess [chocolate-milk](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chocolate-milk) *could* work for the first, but I don't think it would be easily found.

What do you all think? Give me examples for both, if you would, please.

**EDIT:** Would the tags [water-in-oil](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/water-in-oil) and [oil-in-water](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oil-in-water) suffice? Or do we need something just beyond this? Do we actually need this at all? Let me know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've never heard the term [chocolate-milk](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chocolate-milk) in this context - but [mayonnaise](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mayonnaise) for water in the oil is common here.

I think that [water-in-oil](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/water-in-oil) and [oil-in-water](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oil-in-water) are much clearer and cross-culture (especially as we have a lot of users for whom English is not their first language).

Answer (score 2):

Personally I know of [chocolate-milk](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chocolate-milk) and [milkshake](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/milkshake) being the two slang terms, but I don't know how well known or common those would be as tags. Possibly just doing [fluid-cross-contamination](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fluid-cross-contamination) or [fluid-contamination](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fluid-contamination) would work as an umbrella term.

I also agree that [oil-in-water](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oil-in-water) and [water-in-oil](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/water-in-oil) are sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Emulsion is the first proper or classic term that comes to mind- as they don't properly mix - they separate over time... think of vinaigrette ...

Comment: You are technically correct, but I think what I'd be looking for is something less technical and more descriptive. The reason for two different tags is to separate the two issues, as while the end product can be the same, what is happening is completely different.

Comment: I do think your o-in-w and w-in-o are sufficient though - it should be clear which the poster should choose...

Comment: I'm tending to agree with you here. Was hoping for others to chime in. Also, putting information into the wikis should make it very clear what is meant for each.

Comment: Try it and see - sure it won't be the last to be edited if it doesn't pan out, may also be just what is needed...

Comment: Could the downvoter explain why the correct technical term deserves a downvote - ....

Comment: I didn't downvote you here, but would like to explain on the Meta site, downvotes don't *exactly* mean the same thing as on the main site. All the downvote means here is they disagree with what you are suggesting (ie: they would not want this used as the tag), not that there is anything overtly wrong with it. It's more about someone's opinion here, so consider it as such.

Comment: Ok, I do understand why it may not be the best tag as well!! But a voiced opinion to go with would not go amiss...

Comment: Oh, I couldn't agree more with you about the voiced opinion. I appreciate those as well. Some reason as to *why* someone downvoted goes a long way.